# Bar of proportion of two variables

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am having a pandas dataframe as shown below

```
import numpy as np

data = {
'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
'baseline': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
'endline': [1, 0, np.nan, 1, 0, 0, 1, np.nan, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 0, 1, np.nan, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, np.nan, 1, 0, np.nan, 0, 0, 0, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0, np.nan, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
'gender': ['male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female']

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(n = 5)
```

The challenge is the endline column may have some missing values. My goal is to have 2 bars for each variable side by side as shown below.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of the expected graph? What should happen to the missing values?

Comment: Missing values should be excluded

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5)); sns.barplot(data=df.melt(id_vars=['id'], value_vars=['baseline', 'endline']), x='id', y='value', hue='variable')` ?

Comment: Or `sns.barplot(data=df.melt(value_vars=['baseline', 'endline']), x='variable', y='value', estimator=lambda x: np.sum(x)/np.size(x)*100, ci=None)`?

Comment: @JohanC the second approach is perfect. Could you kindly modify it to allow for labels? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seaborn prefers its data in "long form". Pandas' melt can convert the given dataframe to combine the 'baseline' and 'endline' columns.

By default, `sns.barplot` shows the mean when there are multiple y-values belonging to the same x-value. You can use a different estimator, e.g. summing the values and dividing by the number of values to get a percentage.

Here is some code to get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'id': range(1, 51),
'baseline': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
'endline': [1, 0, np.nan, 1, 0, 0, 1, np.nan, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 0, 1, np.nan, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, np.nan, 1, 0, np.nan, 0, 0, 0, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0, np.nan, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.barplot(data=df.melt(value_vars=['baseline', 'endline']),
                 x='variable', y='value',
                 estimator=lambda x: np.sum(x) / np.size(x) * 100, ci=None,
                 color='cornflowerblue')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.1f %%', fontsize=20)

sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True)
ax.grid(True, axis='y')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with percentages]

Comment: Do you know why ```ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.1f %%', fontsize=20)``` throws the error AxesSubplot’ object has no attribute ‘bar_label’ in Python 3.6?

Comment: You need matplotlib 3.5. In general, you should try to avoid running old versions, as each day hard-working volunteers are solving bugs and adding features. As an aside, Stackoverflow contains many post about how to mimic or improve `bar_label`s behaviour, also for older versions.

Comment: I wanted to produce the same graph with the ```hue = 'gender'```. However, I realize the labels appear only on first bar. Any guidance on the work around? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When working with hue, multiple containers are created. In that case, you can loop through each of them: `for container in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.1f %%', ...)`

Comment: Thanks so much! i sincerely appreciate